# Failed to download resource "openexr--exr"

Tags: php, homebrew

I am trying to install composer for php using homebrew on my macbook macOS 10.14. but I am getting errors.

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: composer: Failed to download resource "openexr--exr"
Download failed: https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr-images/raw/master/TestImages/AllHalfValues.exr
Nanas-MacBook-Pro:~ nanaasare$

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem trying to install openexr as a dependency for another formula using Homebrew on the Mac.

The problem appears to be that the openexr repo changed its primary branch name from `master` to `main`. So the download URL has also changed.

I worked around this by editing the brew formula:

1. `brew edit openexr`
2. The file will open in your default text editor. Search for the following line:

```
    url "https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr-images/raw/master/TestImages/AllHalfValues.exr"
```

3. Change `master` in this line to `main`:

```
    url "https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr-images/raw/main/TestImages/AllHalfValues.exr"
```

4. Save and close the file.
5. On the command line, run brew install again: `brew install openexr`

Answer (score 0):

you should run "brew install openexr"